# Can't use Shift-Ctrl-PgUp/PgDn to move tabs in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When I use Linux, I used to use `Shift-Ctrl-PgUp/PgDn` to move tabs in Chrome, they are quite convenient. When I moved to Windows, this shortcut stops to work. I failed to figure out the reason. Anybody know why?

```
Windows 7 64-bit
Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 dev-m (64-bit)
```

Comment: The feature was originally added to Chromium in order to honor the GTK+ custom of using those keys to reorder tabs. ❧ The feature is Linux-only because Evan requested for it to be Linux-only in the subject line of [this issue thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=21594). ❧ Still, I don't know why he requested for it to be Linux-only.  Many Linux users also use Windows and Mac OS, and they might want these keyboard shortcuts to be available there too.  ❧  It would be good if someone would file a Chromium issue and request that they make the feature work on all platforms.

Answer (score 4):

I can't figure out why they removed (or failed to add) that shortcut on Windows, but I just found a Chrome extension that solves the problem:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-to-reo/moigagbiaanpboaflikhdhgdfiifdodd?hl=en

Do note that I haven't tried this on Mac, only on Windows. But I can confirm that it works on Windows. And since your question was about Windows, I'm pretty this extension is what you're looking for.

Comment: After installing extension, needed to restart chrome.

Comment: Giving an insight on this, it is working on Ubuntu I can confirm. Surprisingly it does not work on chromeos as well, though not sure if it was not the case before.

Comment: Also, this extension is only for windows and mac. It does not support ChromeOS as of now.